# Validating client (non-istio) certificate at the Ingress gateway in my AKS cluster

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

I have a scenario where an external app (not on Istio) is calling our services to get some data. Client sends in it's certificate in the WebRequestHandler that we validate as a way to authenticate the client. Can this be done at the ingress-gateway level?

Please note that I am also terminating the TLS traffic at the gateway and forwarding the request to the corresponding services on different pods based on http url-regex matching. I am also okay to validate the certificate in my service's code given it reaches the service as it is (excuse me for sounding naive here, I am very new to this).

Thank you!

Comment: I think you could try to use [envoy filter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) to do the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want mutual TLS between an external service and Istio's Ingress Gateway then that's possible and is documented here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/